# Unable to connect to VPN (PPTP). Please help!

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp

I have registered an account with PureVPN and bought a static IP from them. I tried to setup the PPTP connection on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but it is not working.

Here are some screenshots for the setup:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq0Wz.jpg

I tried to set the security to "All Available (Default)", but still couldn't connect.

Here is a screenshot of the problem I am having when trying to connect:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/riPe3.jpg

And my firewall is turned off:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl8UW.jpg

I am really desperate by now and need this VPN connection very much. Could anyone here please help me overcome this issue?

Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, an incorrect time is the problem.

Check your time and make sure that it is set correctly.